# Incrementing diagonally

Tags: loops, increment

```
        if (shape.equals("diagonal")){
                    for (int row = 0; row <= size; row ++){
                        for (int col = 0 ; col < size; col ++ ){

                            if ( col % 4 == 0 ){
                                System.out.print("*");
                            } else {
                                System.out.print("$");
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }



*$$$*$$$*$$$*$$$*
$*$$$*$$$*$$$*$$$
$$*$$$*$$$*$$$*$$
same as it go down
```

My goal is to print the code above and it continues til 17 by 17 output is create

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
if (col % 4 == 0 )
```

with

```
if ( (col+row)%4 == 0 )
```